# Activity which adds an item to a list with images

Tags: java, android, variables, android-intent

I want to make an activity which will add an item to a list with images from another activity by pressing a button. I'm working with a base adapter for making the list with images and text. The images is selected from sd card and the text is entered in an edit text.

This is the activity from which a new item will be added:

```
public class Add extends Menu_Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ImageView img;
    Bitmap bmp;
    private static int REQ_IMAGE = 1;
    String title = null;
    String picturePath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add);
        ss = new Start_Screen();

        Button btnBrowse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBrowse);
        Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSong);
        EditText etTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
        title = etTitle.getText().toString();

        if (title != null) {
            btnSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        btnBrowse.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnBrowse:
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, REQ_IMAGE);
            break;
        case R.id.btnSave:

            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQ_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
```

When btnSave is clicked i want that a new item to appear in this activity:

```
public class Start_Screen extends Menu_Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.start_screen);
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.soundslist);

List<Bitmap> lbmp = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
List<String> ltitles=new ArrayList<String>();

lbmp.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cobblestone));
lbmp.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));

ltitles.add("I'm Blue");
ltitles.add( "Eminem-Lose Yourself");


Bitmap[] bmp = lbmp.toArray(new Bitmap[lbmp.size()]);
String[] titles=ltitles.toArray(new String[ltitles.size()]);
Custom_Adapter adapter = new Custom_Adapter(this, bmp, titles);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the imagepath as an intent extra to your Start_Screen and decode it there in the same way you decoded the file in the previous activity.

Comment: And how do i add a new ListItem?

Comment: You have to write a method in your custom adapter that takes a bitmap and a string as a parameter and adds those to the adapter's data sources. Make your adapter take lists as paramters rather than arrays and you'll be able to easily append stuff using list.add(Object). After you're done adding the elements call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.